# Add a filter to an action

Tags: filters, actions

I feel like this is a really simple question, but I can't seem to find anything. I want to add a filter to an action, so I can run `preg_replace` on it to add a class to a link.

The action is:

```
do_action("tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content");
```

This is what I'm trying to use for my filter, I'm sure I'm doing something dumb:

```
function fix_tribe_button_class($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/tribe-events-button/i", "tribe-events-button button", $content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter("the_content", "fix_tribe_button_class", 999, 1);
```

I've even tried doing `return "test";` to see if maybe I was matching incorrectly. It just didn't affect anything at all.

Comment: You can't filter action hooks (unless you filter their final outcome e.g `ob_start(); /*do action*/ echo apply_filters(.., ob_get_clean())`), I think you need [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) ?

Comment: What exactly is `tribe_events`? Do you have a link?

Comment: @kaiser it's a plugin for events: https://theeventscalendar.com/product/wordpress-events-calendar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action name suggests it is run `_after_the_content`, not within the `the_content` itself, so you might have to do something different here like @SamuelElh is suggesting...

You would add a function to the action with early priority to buffer, then add a filter to the final output with a late priority:

```
add_action('tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content','tribe_events_single_event_buffer_start',0);
function tribe_events_single_event_buffer_start() {ob_start();}

add_action('tribe_events_single_event_after_the_content','tribe_events_single_event_buffer_end',999);
function tribe_events_single_event_buffer_end() {
    return apply_filters('tribe_events_single_event_filter_output',ob_get_clean());
}

function tribe_events_single_event_filter_output($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/tribe-events-button/i", "tribe-events-button button", $content);
    return $content;
}
```